# Using a hidden input value to show or hide elements

Tags: jquery, search, hidden

I'm working on a website for which I have to display stores that deliver to the zip code provided by the user. All the stores have their own div and the zip code is sent to a hidden input after the search box has been used or the user has logged on. This part isn't hard for me to figure out. The part where the information in the hidden input gets sent to the page where the stores are listed is also not a tough one. The part I'm having trouble with is showing only the relevant divs. I want the divs of the stores to contain the zip codes they deliver to in one way or another (whether it is visible or not). Since they all deliver to more than one zip code, I was wondering how you would recommend me to use the value from the hidden input to scan for a certain zip code and then display the div in which it is present.

Maybe my phrasing makes it more complicated than it really seems. The basic idea is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="zip" value="x">

<div id="store" style="display:none;">Somewhere inside here are some zip codes, one of them has value x (could also be in another</div>

<script>Some code to make the display style of this particular div "block;"</script>
```

I hope someone can help me with this, it has been quite a struggle.

Thanks a million in advance. Peace and much love. One!

Comment: In other words: I want to display a div that contains a specific element

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="zip" value="x">

<div CLASS="store" style="display:none;">Somewhere inside here are some zip codes, one of them has value x (could also be in another</div>

<script>
// check each store and show them if they make reference to the given zip code.
$(".store").each(function(){
if(this.text().indexOf($("#zip").val()) >= 0)
    this.css({display: "block"});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<script type"text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var temp=$("#store").text();
    if(temp.indexOf($("#zip").val())!=-1){
    $("#store").show();//show this div;mark as visible
    }

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem actually. It was easier than expected.

If there would be a hidden input with the id "zipcode" the code essentially contains the following crucial elements:

```
Function() {

var value = $("#zipcode").val();

$("div:contains(" + value + ")").css("display", "block");

}
```

The zip codes in the div can be in a hidden span in case you do not want them shown. In IE the span is visible for some reason, but you can work your way around that by using hidden divs instead of spans.